# Monitor network status on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, networking

How to monitor bytes received/sent in a network session in Ubuntu ?
I'm very new to ubuntu, so dont give links which requires to compile files or so...

Comment: Yeah... we're at 2011 there's little stuff that actually needs to be compiled..., now you can use a gnome-applet to achieve that, or a screenlet (widget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open system-monitor. got to Resources tab. here you can see network, processor, memory uses status. install the following applet witch show status on gnome-panel

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/72652905/indicator-multiload_0.1.orig.tar.gz

install: first cd to folder after extract file

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this from Unity you can use the system monitor as in the following:

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> (the Windows key).
2. Type `monitor` and press System monitor.
3. In the system monitor go to the tab Resources.
4. At the bottom you'll find a graph and numbers on recieved and sent bytes.